# RegExp for allowing whitespaces but containing text

Tags: regex

I know the title might not be the most clearest of all, but i'm looking for a regexp that allows whitespaces (enter and space) but also checks if there is text available.

For example what should and shouldn't be allowed:

What should be allowed:

```
" text "
```

(this also goes for when using enters)

What should not be allowed:

```
" " (or any number of whitespaces only)
```

Does anyone have any idea?

Comment: I'd trim the string and check if there is anything left. `if (trim(str)) ...`

Comment: First, you need to specify the language you are using the regex in. Different languages support different syntax. Second, you need to show your attempt.

Answer (score 3):

You can ignore all whitespace and require at least one non-whitespace character.

This regex is simply: `\S`

That is, match at least one non-whitespace character. And it still allows whitespace as it's not anchored.

The capital letter is important: `\S` is the opposite of `\s`

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by ensuring that the entire string is not a sequence of whitespace characters. You can match it against the follows:

```
^\s*$
```

If it doesn't match, your string is valid. If it does match a string, your string is not valid.

As you can see in the [**DEMO**](http://regex101.com/r/zT2pI5/1), the matched strings are the ones that are not allowed